# How to run DAG from code ? (without getting message: No run dates were found for the given dates and dag interval)

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to debug airflow simple code (from `pycharm`).

I set `executor = DebugExecutor` in `airflow.cfg`

I wrote simple code:

```
from airflow                  import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates      import days_ago

with DAG(dag_id='example_pycharm', schedule_interval=None,start_date=days_ago(3)) as dag:

    def task1_func(ti):
        print('task1: print from task 1')

    def task2_func(ti):
        print('task2: print from task 2')


    task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='task1',  python_callable=task1_func, provide_context=True)
    task2 = PythonOperator(task_id='task2',  python_callable=task2_func, provide_context=True)

task1 >> task2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.run(start_date=days_ago(3))
```

But I'm getting message:

```
INFO - No run dates were found for the given dates and dag interval.
```

How can I run this simple `DAG` from pycharm (in debug mode) ?